# User requested to close account, should they be 'forcefully' logged out?

Tags: interaction-design, user-behavior, user-expectation, accounts, delete

From a purely `UX` viewpoint:

1. User clicks on 'Close my Account'
2. After requisite begging to not close and their persistence, the account, on the Server is 'Closed'.

What should happen on the UI after the fact? Should the user be allowed to use the site until they log out? Or, surgically logged out and redirected to Home page with a pertinent message?

What is appropriate `UX`?

The site does not involve Financial or Personal information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better if user is logged out and asked for certain question/survey that helps you to know what was the reason of closing the account.

- If user is allowed to access even after they delete/close their account, one wouldn't be very sure, what they did was successfully done. Or they would not understand the actual meaning of what they have done.
- If user is thrown back to homepage/login page directly it will be like too quick for user too understand what just happened, and like an insult of throwing out of something suddenly.
- If user asks for closing an account, better would be

  1. Asking for confirmation
  2. Taking them to page/screen where you might ask the reason. So once again they know what they are about to do. And you get the users reason of this action.
  3. Finally displaying a message saying thank you in whatever way you can for being the member and would love to have them back. And now you throw user where you want with logged out as background activity.

> All these depends on whatever way you want to treat your users. Also point 1. & 2. could happen all at once, if you want it quick.

Thank You!

Hope this might help you somehow.

(Bare me for the format as I wrote this from mobile device)

Answer (score 1):

I find [divy3993 answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/108472/84175) correct.

But I'll add that there should be a provision for the user to get a copy of his personal data (if any) before deleting the account.

Anyway, once the account is deleted (or marked as deleted), the user should be logged out and sent to the main page.